# How do I remove all nonalphabetic characters from a string?

Tags: c#

I have to write a program that checks if the input is a palindrome and in this code I am required to have a method that removes all nonalphabetic characters from the string. What is the best way to do this? Is it better to convert the input into an array (right now I am doing it as a string)? I do not want to write a loop for each individual character or put each one into trim. Will trim take off things in the middle as well?

I also am not allowed to use regex, enumerable, or throw new exception, as professor is not a fan of the latter two and the first one does not work, it only throws errors.

The way I am doing it does not seem like the most efficient way to go about this.

My code is here:

```
 public partial class frmPalindrome : Form
{
    public frmPalindrome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //allows btnCheck to take in user input in txtEnterWordPhrase and check if it is a palindrome
    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsValidData())
            {
                string strPhrase = Convert.ToString(txtEnterWordPhrase.Text);
                string strCleanPhrase = CharacterStrip(strPhrase);

                txtPalindrome.Text = Convert.ToString(IsPalindrome(strCleanPhrase));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //catches any other exceptions
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
        }
    }

    //a method that cuts all the nonalphabetic characters out of txtEnterWordPhrase
    public string CharacterStrip(string Phrase)
    {
        //neither of these seem very efficient
        //Phrase = Phrase.Trim(new Char[] {' ', '&', '*', ',', '-', '_', '/', '\', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',  });

        while (Phrase.IndexOf(" ") >= 0)
        {
           int intIndex = Phrase.IndexOf(" ");
           Phrase.Remove(intIndex, 1);
        }

        return Phrase;
    }

    //checks if the input is a palindrome
    public bool IsPalindrome(string Phrase)
    {
        //not sure how to do this yet
        return true; //have not built this method yet
    }

    //checks that the input is valid
    public bool IsValidData ()
    {
        return IsString(txtEnterWordPhrase, "Enter a Word or Phrase"); //have not built this validation method yet
    }

    //checks that the input in txtEnterWordPhrase is a string
    public bool IsString(TextBox Textbox, string Name)
    {
        decimal Number = 0m;

        if (Decimal.TryParse(Textbox.Text, out Number))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Name + " must be a word or phrase.", "Entry Error");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;

    }

    //allows btnExit to close the program
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    //a method that clears txtPalindrome and returns focus to txtEnterWordPhrase
    private void ClearResults(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPalindrome.Text = "";
        txtEnterWordPhrase.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you think using .Trim is so inefficient? I'd say it is quite efficient at what it does, but it doesn't do what I think you expect; it will only remove those characters from the beginning and end of your string.

Comment: @andresairr I did not realize it only did the beginning and end, I am looking for something that works throughout the entire string. If the user inputs "test 12 test" I need to turn it into "testtest"

Comment: [codereview.se] (remember to read help before asking)

Comment: @user202729 are you just trying to show me another site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there are a couple of problems with your example method, `CharacterStrip`. `Phrase.Trim()` will only trim characters from the beginning and end of your string, so as soon as it encounters a character not in your array, it will assume it belongs, and stop processing. So, it won't remove all non-alphabetic characters from your string.

Secondly, `Phrase.Remove()` returns a new string with that 1 character removed - which you are not using. You probably meant to assign the result to `Phrase` again. An important principle in C# to learn is the immutability of strings: you can't change a string once you have it, you can only create a new string from it, in this case one that has the character(s) from the given index removed. This said, even with this amendment your while loop won't strip non-alphabetic characters out anyway, it would only remove spaces.

So, before worrying about efficiency, let's start with something that works, however inelegant:

```
public string CharacterStrip(string phrase)
{
    string[] chars = new string[] { " ", "&", "*", ",", "-", "_", "/", "\\", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", };

    foreach (string c in chars)
        phrase = phrase.Replace(c, "");

    return phrase;
}
```

This has the drawback that you will need to maintain your array of characters (stored as strings) to include all non-alphabetic characters, which it doesn't at present, but it's a start.

Another approach, using a loop over your original string follows, leveraging [`Char.IsLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Char.IsLetter)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Char_IsLetter_System_Char_), as Matt's answer suggested. This means you don't need to maintain an array of characters to remove.

```
string output = "";
foreach (char c in phrase)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
        output = output + c;
}

return output;
```

However, this will still create new strings over and over for each loop iteration (remember that's how strings work), which isn't very efficient.
Most efficiently yet, you can use the fantastic [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, which maintains a *mutable* collection of character/strings to assemble into a single string when you're done. It's worth reading about if you're interested in doing lots of string manipulation in an efficient way:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in phrase)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
        builder.Append(c);
}

return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Would the downvoter take the time to explain why, please?

Comment: I am not allowed to use StringBuilder as my professor is not a fan, but your middle example worked perfectly

Comment: Interesting. What exactly does your professor not like about `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I am honestly not sure, it is a summer semester so she runs through the textbook and when we got to this she said "Don't use this, I don't like it" and kept going

Answer (score 1):

An easy LINQ solution would be something like

```
    string exampleString = "123 Example Text 456"; 
    string onlyAlpha = new string(exampleString.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(onlyAlpha);
```

Output:

```
Example Text
```

There's not really any way you can avoid looping through the string at some level.

Comment: Will this delete any numbers in the middle of the text as well?

Comment: Yes. It is essentially going through the entire string and only keeping characters that return true when passed in to Char.IsLetter().

Answer (score 0):

As easy as :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
phrase= rgx.Replace(phrase, "");
```

Comment: .NET strings do not have a method `replaceAll`. That would be Java.